# Invoking multiple commands using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am invoking ProcessBuilder with the following command-line:

`{"cmd.exe", "/c", "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools\\..\\..\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat && msbuild"}`

The process throws this exception:

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

If I remove `&& msbuild` the error goes away (so this isn't an issue of quoting). Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a windows machine knocking about, but my guess would be to quote the `&&` and `msbuild` as separate array entries.

```
{"cmd.exe",
"/c",
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat",
"&&",
"msbuild"}
```

Comment: If I could reach through the monitor and kiss you I would :) Thank you very much!